# Transforming column of chr string into date in R

Tags: r, date

I have two columns that are supposed to be dates on my dataset (imported from .csv file)

```
A tibble: 18 × 6
   date1      date2   
   <chr>      <chr>      
 1 21/02/2024 26/02/2024 
 2 12/02/2024 14/02/2024 
 3 12/02/2024 13/02/2024 
 4 09/02/2024 11/02/2024 
 5 10/02/2024 14/02/2024 
 6 27/02/2024 02/03/2024 
 7 10/02/2024 14/02/2024 
 8 02/02/2024 04/02/2024
```

I want howerver to further analyse my data, and I want R to read them as dates. In the format dd/mm/yyyy

I have tried many combinations, and always get an error. my latest try is as follows

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
  select(date1) %>%
    as.Date(format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

the error:

```
Error in as.Date.default(., format = "%d-%m-%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”
```

I have seen the as.date coding format many times and i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you want to keep the column in `dataset`? If so, I think you want `dataset %>% mutate(date1 = as.Date(date1, format="%d/%m/%Y"))`. Your current code is selecting just the `date1` column, still as a `tibble`/`data.frame`, which can not be converted to a date directly.

Answer (score 0):

The format entered in `as.Date` needs to match the particular format of the text in your input columns.

```r
library(dplyr)

dataset
#>        date1      date2
#> 1 21/02/2024 26/02/2024
#> 2 12/02/2024 14/02/2024
#> 3 12/02/2024 13/02/2024
#> 4 09/02/2024 11/02/2024
#> 5 10/02/2024 14/02/2024
#> 6 27/02/2024 02/03/2024
#> 7 10/02/2024 14/02/2024
#> 8 02/02/2024 04/02/2024

dataset %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.Date(., format = "%d/%m/%Y")))
#>        date1      date2
#> 1 2024-02-21 2024-02-26
#> 2 2024-02-12 2024-02-14
#> 3 2024-02-12 2024-02-13
#> 4 2024-02-09 2024-02-11
#> 5 2024-02-10 2024-02-14
#> 6 2024-02-27 2024-03-02
#> 7 2024-02-10 2024-02-14
#> 8 2024-02-02 2024-02-04
```

#### Data

```
dataset <- structure(list(date1 = c("21/02/2024", "12/02/2024", "12/02/2024", 
                                    "09/02/2024", "10/02/2024", "27/02/2024", "10/02/2024", "02/02/2024"
), date2 = c("26/02/2024", "14/02/2024", "13/02/2024", "11/02/2024", 
             "14/02/2024", "02/03/2024", "14/02/2024", "04/02/2024")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                           -8L))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it return on the format ddmmyyyy instead of yyyymmdd?

Comment: Not if you want to keep them as date objects.  See `format()` if you want to turn them back into strings.

Comment: Date objects in R are stored as an integer that's the number of days since 1970-01-01. What you see in the output is the print method for the Date class formatting that integer as an ISO date. Like Dave2e said, keep them as Date while you're working with them and use format() if you need to display them in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

Base R alternative

```r
cx = grep("date", colnames(dataset))
# conversion to Date
dataset[cx] = lapply(dataset[cx], as.Date, "%d/%m/%Y") 
# format for presentation (later on)
lapply(dataset[cx], format, "%d/%m/%Y") 
rm(cx) # optional
```